# Formatting string dates to always follow yyyy-mm-dd format (non-epoch)

Tags: javascript

I have 3 different clients (Android, iOS and Web) all hitting the same endpoint parsing a date string which needs to be stored as yyyy-mm-dd. Android and iOS date pickers both seem to be parsing the correct format but excluding the zeros for months and days in the single digits i.e 2019-8-9 instead of 2019-08-09.

Moment.js does't seem to have a solution to this. I would like a solution that can be handled server side in vanilla js so as to not need updates to be made to the Android and iOS apps functions that parse the data.

This is my current solution. Works as it should. Curious to see if anyone can come up with a cleaner/leaner solution.

```
function checkDateFormat(date){
    return new Promise (resolve=>{
        if(date.length == 8){
            // Both month and day are single digits and should be fixed
            var firstFix = date.substr(0, 5) + "0" + date.substr(5);
            var secondFix = firstFix .substr(0, 8) + "0" + firstFix.substr(8);
            resolve(secondFix);
        } else if (date.length == 9){    
            if(date.substr(6,1) == "-"){
                // Month is single digit and should be fixed
                var monthFix = date.substr(0, 5) + "0" + date.substr(5);
                resolve(monthFix);
            } else {
                // Day is single digit and should be fixed
                var dayFix = date.substr(0, 8) + "0" + date.substr(8);
                resolve(dayFix);
            }            
        } else {
            resolve(date);
        }        
    });
}
```

Should resolve string consistently as yyyy-mm-dd and never yyyy-m-dd or yyyy-mm-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple regular expression replace would be enough :

```js
console.log( '2000-1-2'.replace(/\b\d\b/g, '0$&') )
```

Comment: Cleanest and simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

If you know that's the only formatting issue you can expect, you could just make a function to shove a zero at the start of any digit smaller than 10, and another to split the string so you can parse the day and month values.

```js
let goodDate = "2019-08-09";
let badDate = "2019-8-9";

function paddedZero(str){
  return parseInt(str) > 9 ? str : `0${parseInt(str)}`;
}

function formatDateStr(str){
  let [year, month, day] = str.split("-");
  return `${year}-${paddedZero(month)}-${paddedZero(day)}`;
}

console.log(formatDateStr(goodDate));
console.log(formatDateStr(badDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
function padZero(str) {
  return str.length === 1 ? '0' + str : str;
}

function checkDateFormat(date){
    date = date.split("-");
    date[1] = padZero(date[1]);
    date[2] = padZero(date[2]);
    return date.join("-");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure why you need a Promise here since I can't see any real async code, but anyway, the core part would be:

```
const ensureDateFormat = (date) => 
  new Date(date).toISOString().substr(0, 10);
```

If you want to return a promise, you could always return a resolved promise:

```
const ensureDateFormat = (date) => 
  Promise.resolve(new Date(date).toISOString().substr(0, 10));
```

**Notice** that this is assume you don't have year prior 0 or after 9999. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Promise was due to requiring the resolve on my end, should have edited for the question but thanks for the answer, short but sweet